# React Typescript: How to type location in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a routing like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <PageRouting >
    <Route exact component={DashboardPage} path={routes.ROUTE_MAIN} />
    <Route component={DocumentsPage} path={routes.ROUTE_DOCUMENTS} />
    <Route component={SettingsPage} path={routes.ROUTE_SETTINGS} />
  </PageRouting>
  <Redirect to={routes.ROUTE_MAIN} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Routes are literal types:

```
const routes = {
  ROUTE_MAIN: '/',
  ROUTE_DASHBOARD: '/',
  ROUTE_DOCUMENTS: '/documents',
  ROUTE_SETTINGS: '/settings',
}
```

I want my location with type:

```
type routesKeys = keyof typeof routes

type LocationTypes {
  pathname: routesKeys
}

const location = useLocation<LocationTypes>()
```

But 'location.pathname' is a type of string, not 'routesKeys'.

How can I set type for location.pathname?

EDIT:

'location.pathname' should be a type of:

```
type routesPaths = typeof routes[routesKeys]
```

Comment: may be with an enum  like `enum routes { ROUTE_MAIN = '/', ROUTE_DASHBOARD= '/',
  ROUTE_DOCUMENTS =  '/documents',
  ROUTE_SETTINGS =  '/settings'}`

Comment: Also you could define the type for the keys of `routes` as string.

Comment: @antoineso I'm afraid that this doesn't style location.pathname.

Comment: @shn: Yes, of course. I wanted to use this 'pathname' in the function with parameter of type routesKeys. If it will be impossible I'll do this for sure.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way to do this just by passing types to `useLocation`.  The generic on `useLocation`, which you are setting to `LocationTypes`, actually refers to the property `location.state`.  `location.pathname` is always just a `string`.

You would have to either extends the typings of these packages or assert correctness via `as`.

I don't have a ton of experience extending packages, so I don't know how to make this work correctly.  I think you can only extend an interface and not a type?  Maybe someone else knows.

```
declare module 'history' {
    export type Pathname = keyof typeof routes;
}
```

The assertion approach is basically wrapping the built-in function with your own.

```
import {useLocation as useLocationImported} from "react-router-dom";
import {State, Location} from "history";

export const useLocation = <S extends State = State>() => 
    useLocationImported<S>() as Location<S> & {pathname: routesKeys}
```

```
const location = useLocation();
const path = location.pathname; // type is "ROUTE_MAIN" | "ROUTE_DASHBOARD" | "ROUTE_DOCUMENTS" | "ROUTE_SETTINGS"
```

Edit: on further thought, I don't think you want to do this.  These sort of typings make it so that the path is always an exact match to one of your routes, but in reality that's not the case 100% of the time.  You will create problems if you assume that it is.